# Using curl to get cookie value from website 1 and input it into website 2

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I want to use `curl` in the terminal to get a number value from website1 and input that value into website2. The value of the cookie is a number and that number is the only thing written on that page.There is pretty short time interval like 1 second because the number on the first website keeps changing. So what is the best way to do it?.

Comment: you want to use terminal `curl` command or php `curl_*` statements ?

Comment: terminal `curl` @TechJS